# $X\setminus Bd(M)=Int(M)\cup Int(X\setminus M) $

Tags: general-topology

> Let $M$ be a subset of the pological space $X$, prove that  $X\setminus  Bd(M)=Int(M)\cup Int(X\setminus M) $

**(Boundary=Bd)**

My solution:

let $a\in X\setminus  Bd(M)$ then $\overset{?}{\Rightarrow } a \in Int(M) $ or $a\in Int(X\setminus M)$, indeed lets assume that $a \displaystyle \notin Int(M) $ and $a \displaystyle \notin Int(X\setminus M) $ that mean tha $a \in  X\setminus  Int(M)$ and $a  \in  X\setminus Int(X\setminus M)$ which leads to a contradiction since  $a $ can't be in $ Int(M)$ and $ Int(X\setminus M)$

so $X\setminus  Bd(M)\subseteq Int(M)\cup Int(X\setminus M) $

It's enough to show that $Int(M)\cup Int(X\setminus M)\subseteq X\setminus  Bd(M)$

let $a\in Int(M)\cup Int(X\setminus M)  $ if $a\in Int(M)\Rightarrow a  \displaystyle \notin Bd(M) $

if $a\in Int(X\setminus M) \Rightarrow a  \displaystyle \notin Bd(M) $, indeed if $a\in Bd(M)$,  $(Bd(M)=Cl(M)\cap Cl(X\setminus M))$ we get $a\in Cl(M)\cap Cl(X\setminus M)\cap Int(X\setminus M) $ wich means that it exist an open set $U$ such that $U\cap M \neq \emptyset$ and $U \subseteq X\setminus M$ which is a contradiction. hence, $a \in X\setminus  Bd(M)$

I am not very happy with my proof, would be considered correct ?

Comment: If you know that $X\setminus \overline{A}=\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)$
for any set $A$. then the proof can be done with our retorting to $x\in ...$ type of arguments:

$\partial(B)=\overline{B}\cap(\overline{X\setminus B)}$ and so,
$X\setminus \partial(B)=(X\setminus\overline{B})\cup\big(X\setminus(\overline{X\setminus B)}\big)=\operatorname{int}(X\setminus B)\cup\operatorname{int}(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof has a few holes in it. Now, sometimes it is rather useful to used results you may already know about relations between closure and interior. For example, if you know that $X\setminus \overline{A}=\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)$
for any set $A$,  then the proof can be done with our retorting to $x\in ...$ type of arguments:

$\partial(M)=\overline{M}\cap(\overline{X\setminus M)}$ and so,
$X\setminus \partial(M)=(X\setminus\overline{M})\cup\big(X\setminus(\overline{X\setminus M)}\big)=\operatorname{int}(X\setminus M)\cup\operatorname{int}(M)$

---

That  $X\setminus \overline{A}=\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)$ can be proved with $x\in...$ type arguments, or by noticing simple facts about interior and closure:
Since $X\setminus \overline{A}$ is open an contained in $X\setminus A$, then by ddefinition of interior of a set (largest open set contained in given set), $X\setminus\overline{A}\subset\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)$.
Since $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)$ is an open set fully contained in $X\setminus A$, it does not contained any accumulation points of $A$ (otherwise, it would contain elements  of $A$), hence $\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)\subset(X\setminus \overline{A})$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof of the fact that $X\setminus\partial M\subset\operatorname{int}(M)\cup\operatorname{int}(X\setminus M)$ is not correct, since you don't why it leads to a contradiction. Id $a\in X\setminus\partial M$, then $a\notin\overline{M}\cap\overline{X\setminus M}$. On the other hand, $a\in M$ or $a\in X\setminus M$. Suppose that $a\in M$. Since $a\notin\overline{X\setminus M}$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $a$ such that $V\cap(X\setminus M)=\emptyset$. In other words, $V\subset M$. So, $M$ is a neighborhood of $a$, which is the same thing as asserting that $x\in\operatorname{int}(M)$. The case in which $a\in X\setminus M$ is similar.

Now, suppose that $a\in\operatorname{int}(M)$. Then $\operatorname{int}(M)$ is a neighborhood of $a$ and $\operatorname{int}(M)\cap(X\setminus M)=\emptyset$. So, $a\notin\overline{X\setminus M}$. In particular, $a\notin\overline X\cap\overline{X\setminus M}=\partial M$. By the same argument, if $a\in\operatorname{int}(X\setminus M)$, then $a\notin\partial M$. So, if $a\in\operatorname{int}(M)\cup\operatorname{int}(X\setminus M)$, then $a\in X\setminus\partial M$.

Answer (score 2):

More simply:

$x\in X\setminus Int(M)$ iff no nbhd of $x$ is a subset of $M$ iff every nbhd of $x$ contains a member of $X\setminus M$ iff $x\in \overline {X\setminus M}.$

Replacing $M$ with $X\setminus M$ in the above sentence, we see that  $x\in X\setminus Int (X\setminus M)$ iff $x\in \overline {X\setminus (X\setminus M )}=\overline M .$

In other words $Int (M)=X\setminus  \overline {X\setminus M}$ and $Int( X\setminus M)=\overline M.$

So the result follows immediately from de Morgan's laws (for unions, intersections, & complements of sets) and from the def'n $Bd(M)=\overline M \cap \overline {X\setminus M}.$

Other symbols for $Bd(M)$ are $Fr(M)$ (for Frontier) and $\partial M$ (LaTex \partial M ). And $M^o$ is also used for $Int(M).$ And $M^c$ is often used for $X\setminus M.$